# Count Multiple Rows from Multiple Table (Power BI)

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to write a Power BI query that can calculate the number of ROWS with a Condition.

Now I have 5 tables- `Table1`, `Table 2`, `Table 3`, `Table 4`, `Table 5`.
Now in those Tables, I have two Column Called `ID` & `Date`. I would like to Count all `ID` where the `Date` is `not Empty

I am trying this Query but it is not helping my cause.

```
All Total Hires = 
SUMX(
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Table1,"A",Table1[Name]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Table2,"A",Table2[Name]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Table3,"A",Table3[Name]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Table4,"A",Table4[Name]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(Table5,"A",Table5[Name])
)
,IF([A] <> NULL, 1, 0))
```

Does Anyone know any solution to this Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using [COUNTROWS](https://dax.guide/countrows/) and [BLANK()](https://dax.guide/blank/). Note: I've assumed that the Date is null/blank and not ' ' type of empty.

```
Table1 Non Blanks= CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table1'), FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[Date] <> BLANK())
```

You create a measure per table, and add them together or

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table1'), FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[Date] <> BLANK())
+ CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table2'), FILTER('Table2', 'Table2'[Date] <> BLANK())
+ and Table3 etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this below **measure**-

```
count_id = 
COUNTROWS(
    UNION(
        FILTER(Table_1, Table_1[date] <> BLANK()),
        FILTER(Table_2, Table_2[date] <> BLANK())
    )
)
```